# sqlite database on listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I'm creating an android book that has 6 season whithin sqlite database but listview take several seconds to load data.
I know that I sholud implement onscroll methode to do this,but I don't know how manage it
my code is:

```
public class list_story extends ListActivity{
private database db;
private String[] Name;

private String sea;
Context c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_story);
    db = new database(this);
    Bundle ex = getIntent().getExtras();
    sea = ex.getString("sea");
    refresh();
    setListAdapter(new AA());


}

class AA extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    public  AA(){   
    super(list_story.this,R.layout.row_list,Name);
}
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = in.inflate(R.layout.row_list, parent,false);
        txt.setText(Name[position]);
        return (row);

    }   

}
 private void refresh(){
     db.open();
     int s =db.Story_count("content", sea);
     Name = new String[s];
     Fav=new String[s];
     Tasvir=new String[s];
     Scientific=new String[s];
     English=new String[s];

     for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
         Name[i]=db.Story_display(i, sea, "content", 1);
         Fav[i]=db.Story_display(i, sea, "content", 4);
         Tasvir[i]=db.Story_display(i, sea, "content", 5);
         Scientific[i]=db.Story_display(i, sea, "content", 6);
         English[i]=db.Story_display(i, sea, "content", 7);

    }
     db.close();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically every time you try to inflate a new view, you will literally inflate a new view. The problem with that is if you have 100 plus items to put into the list view, well that's 100+ views you've defined. That's extremely inefficient. Use the ViewHolder pattern for ListView, or use a the RecyclerView. Better yet use the RecyclerView. There's a lot of information on the web for both of those. Just look up "how to use ViewHolder in a list view"

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using a single text field and a db i would recomend you to use a simpleCursorAdapter :

```
db = new DBAdapter(this);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        db.getAllTitles(), 
        new String[] { "title" }, 
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you have further questions check this great example https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: I use custome listview and i have +200 record in my database.I deleted unessential codes.